# Изменять размер формы в зависимости от текста в Label

Tags: c#, winforms

Есть форма, на ней лежит Label. Текст, помещаемый в Label, может состоять из пары предложений, а может содержать в себе многострочный список. Форма представляет собой всплывающее окошко возле трея, небольшого размера, это некие уведомления для юзера. Соответственно может возникнуть ситуация, когда текст в метке не помещается на форме. Отмечу, что текст находится в контейнере TableLayout. Как сделать так, чтобы размер формы, а именно высота, зависела от текста в метке, а именно признака, что весь текст виден на экране?

Можно ли сделать что-то вроде этого? 
Считаем размер формы до её показа:

```
while(метка показана не вся)
{
this.height++;
}
```

Использовать скролл в этой форме считаю некрасивым решением, лучше именно увеличить высоту формы.

Answer (score 2):

что-то вроде такого:

```
lbl.WordWrap = true;    
MainForm.Height = lbl.Height + 100; //оставляем 100 пикселей на кнопки
```

кидать код на онЛоад формы или на текстЧейнджед лейбла.

Answer (score 1):

Я не знаю, как измерить сам размер, но вполне возможно найти зависимость ширины от количества символов. Допустим, ваш label - это label1:

```
void label1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e){
  if(label1.Text.Length > какая-то величина){
this.height += 15; //Изменение может быть больше в зависимости от размера шрифта
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Кому интересно, решил проблему так:

```
// подгоняем высоту формы  

// требуемая высота для метки              
                    int pref_height = fTray.lMessage.GetPreferredSize(fTray.lMessage.Size).Height;


                    int cur_height = fTray.lMessage.Height;
                    int diff_height = pref_height - cur_height;

                    if (diff_height>0)
                    {
                        fTray.Height = fTray.Height + diff_height;
                    }
```